# Показ анимации после возврата привычного display

Tags: javascript

Есть такой  пример:

```js
let $div = $('div');

$('button.hide').click(function() {
  $div.one('transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function() {
    $div.toggleClass('undisplay');
  });
  $div.toggleClass('unvisible');
});

$('button.show').click(function() {
  $div.toggleClass('undisplay');
  $div.toggleClass('unvisible');
});
```

```css
.divchik {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease 0s;
  transition: height 300ms ease 0s;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.divchik.unvisible {
  height: 0px;
}

.divchik.undisplay {
  display: none;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divchik"></div>
<button class="hide">Скрыть</button>
<button class="show">Показать</button>
```

Мне нужно выполнить `display:none` после завершения анимации, которая реализована `transition`.
После определенных действий мне нужно вернуть всё как было, но тоже с анимацией на том же свойстве, в данном случае *действие - клик*, а *свойство - height*.
Но проблема в том, что появление идет не плавно. Хотя дисплей я задаю перед тем, как `toggleClass`, который дает нулевую высоту. То есть блок должен возвращать свою высоту плавно.

Но этого не происходит. Наверно, дом обновляется с задержкой для элементов с дисплеем.  Вот решение, до которого я сам додумался:

```js
let $div = $('div');

$('button.hide').click(function() {
  $div.one('transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function() {
    $div.toggleClass('undisplay');
  });
  $div.toggleClass('unvisible');
});

$('button.show').click(function() {
  $div.toggleClass('undisplay');
  setTimeout(() => $div.toggleClass('unvisible'), 0.001);
});
```

```css
.divchik {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease 0s;
  transition: height 300ms ease 0s;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.divchik.unvisible {
  height: 0px;
}

.divchik.undisplay {
  display: none;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divchik"></div>
<button class="hide">Скрыть</button>
<button class="show">Показать</button>
```

Отличие в том, что я даю таймер той строке, которая тугглит класс на `height: 0px`, за счет чего всё возвращается восвояси как и должно.

И вот вопрос: а можно ли не костылить таймером?  А то не хочу костылить на 0.001 милисекунду.  Есть нормальные решения?

Comment: нет смысла использовать _0.001_, скорее всего это число будет просто проигнорировано и будет выбран минимальный доступный интервал. В твоем случае можно опустить задание интервала.

Comment: а зачем делать display:none если высота уже 0 и элемент невидно?

Comment: @Grundy есть чуйка, что при больших объемах вложенности контента для элементов, которым выданы отдельные слои для прорисовки браузером, лучше всего разгрузить память - это дать `display: none`. Иначе есть риск, что анимация будет лагать. Там куда сложнее анимация, чем фейд ин фейд аут, вообщем.

Comment: @Grundy, я в курсе, что таймер округляет. Причем каждый браузер делает это по-разному. Но я не обижусь, если это будет 1ms или даже 10ms. Тем не менее, это костыль и таким остается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственный способ  (если нельзя использовать `visibility: hidden;` вместо `display: none;`), это использовать CSS-animation:

```js
let $div = $('div');

$('button.hide').click(function() {
  $div.one('transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function() {
    $div.toggleClass('undisplay');
  });
  $div.toggleClass('unvisible');
  $div.removeClass('side');
});

$('button.show').click(function() {
  $div.toggleClass('undisplay');
  $div.toggleClass('unvisible');
  $div.addClass('side');
});
```

```css
.divchik {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease 0s;
  transition: height 300ms ease 0s;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.side {
  animation: slide 300ms ease;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

.divchik.unvisible {
  height: 0px;
}

.divchik.undisplay {
  display: none;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divchik"></div>
<button class="hide">Скрыть</button>
<button class="show">Показать</button>
```

Comment: Ну да, с `animation` этот механизм работает как надо. Спасибо.